# The best algorithm for grayscale for tesseract input

Tags: algorithm, tesseract, grayscale

I am working on a project using tesseract library for recognizing word. It doesnt work as I expected, sometimes, it failed with a full focused image. I found that reason is image after my grayscale step is not really good.

The algorithm I'm using come from zxing project:

```
int grey = yuv[inputOffset + x] & 0xff;
pixels[outputOffset + x] = (grey * 0x00010101) | 0xFF000000;
```

Are there any better solution for this case?

**UPDATE**:
I tried to print image after crop and convert and I got a cropped image with expected size but not color. It looks like image is converted to a "purple-green" image. Anyone can help me :( ?

Comment: I don't know the definition of `yuv` that you're using, but it looks like you're stripping off the `v` instead of the `y`. That would certainly account for poor results.

Comment: this code is copied from source, actually, i take apart of image and convert it to grayscale, input image is in YUV format so variable name is yuv

Comment: That's what I'm saying, your conversion to grayscale is wrong. But I can't give specific advice without knowing how the yuv image was generated.

Answer (score 0):

Older version did require a 8bit grayscale tiff for good result. But if you use a version >3 the the best algorithm is to don't do any image preprocessing at all. At least if you don't have special requirements.
The algorithm from zxing would be good if you would have red colored characters ( 0xFF000000 is using only the red channel.)

Comment: Actually I think the `0xFF000000` is just adding a constant alpha to the pixel value, which is probably ignored anyway.

Comment: As i understand, `| 0xFF000000` only add constant alpha. Why it is red channel. I'm using [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library for recognize, this library use tesseract v3.04, isn't is newest version? However, i think image processing with give better result, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality)

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the input image ensuring you get an x height within what Tesseract enjoys as well as using Otsu or adaptive thresholding via Open CV and some morphology filters like opening and dilation provides a set of good preprocessing filtering that produces good results, depending on your input you will need to experiment with the configuration of opening/dilation.

Comment: In my requirement, cropped image is resizeable so it's hard to fix size of input image. Do you have any better solution for image preprocessing without OpenCV library?